# Subspace of a Metric space is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If we have a metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a subspace $A$. Then $A$ is bounded if and only if there exist $x_{0}\in X$ and $r>0$ such that $\rho(a,x_{0})\leq r$ for every $a\in A$.

Can someone help me with the proof of the previous proposition??

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of bounded?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in A$, $A$ bounded $\implies \exists r\gt0$ such that $A\subset B_a(r):=\left\{x\in X|\rho(a,x)\lt r\right\}$ (otherwise it'd be unbounded). Now $a\in A\subset X\implies a\in X$, so you can take $x_0=a$.

Now assume the condition and show that $A$ is bounded. From the condition we have $A\subset B_{x_0}(r)$ which is bounded by definition, thus $A$ is bounded.